# CSS browser cache issue, Is img would have same issue

Tags: css, http

There is known css cache issue when you change your css, browser is not going to realize it unless time expires and everyone seems to be using querystring like ?version=29347 to update css when it changes on server.

But does img has the same issue? When img changes on server, is browser detects it? or do i need similar implementation for img?

Reason i am asking is because i am writing generic implementation for css and would like to know if there are any standards related to img so that it does not have same problem. Instead of just relying on my testing as i can't test all browser or real work scenario

Comment: It depends.. on the browser and whether it is a foreground or background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, images would have the same problem (as would flash, javascript files, or any other media that is cached by the browser).

Using a random dummy query string parameter in your `<img src=>` or `<script src=>` tags should solve the issue for those other cases as well though.